# PHP access to MySQL database from an HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to use a php/html form to delete records from a database. I've set up a test db on my site for this but whenever I try to access the page with the form I get an Internal Server Error (500) page instead. My error logs do not contain anything relevant to why the php might be failing.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Computer Deletion Form</title>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="instructions">
    <h2>Computer Deletion Form</h2>
    <p>Please enter the computer name that needs to be removed from the console. This action is irreversible.</p>
</div>
<div id="computerDeletionForm">
    <form action="delete.php" method="post">
        Your Username: 
        <input name="username" type="text" /><br>
        Your Passphrase:
        <input name="passphrase" type="password" /><br>
        Exact Computer Name: 
        <input name="computerName" type="text" /><br>
        <input name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete Record" />
    </form>
</div>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        mysql_connect("localhost", $_POST['username'], $_POST['passphrase']) or die("Connection Failed");
        mysql_select_db("db_test")or die("Connection Failed");
        $computerName = $_POST['computerName'];
        $query = "delete from testTable where name = '".$computerName."'";
        if(mysql_query($query)) {
            echo "deleted";
        } else {
            echo "fail";
        }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Issue is server-related.

Comment: If you can access your DB using standard MySQL functions, then the problem is with your form. Have you tried the standard method without using POST variables?

Comment: I must point out that using this is highly subjective to SQL injection; *just so you know*.

Comment: I do plan on sanitizing input. I just wanted to make sure I could test it myself first. Could you clarify what the "standard method" for this would be?

Comment: Standard method is `mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx","xxx")` see the manual http://php.net/function.mysql-connect

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything more.

Comment: I'm feeling pretty silly about now. The problem was that permissions for the folder containing this were set incorrectly to 775. I changed it to 755 and it works.

Comment: Ahhhh goodie! Glad to hear it ;-)